# Oracle user created more than 6 months ago

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find users created more than 6 months ago. Trying the following but must be doing something wrong.
Any ideas?
...
WHERE CREATED_TIMESTAMP <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 180);

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my query was fine - the problem was elsewhere in my query.

This works fine:
WHERE CREATED_TIMESTAMP <= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 180);

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, letting Oracle count the months for yu:

```
select *
from all_users
where created < add_months(sysdate, -6)
```

You can add a `TRUNC` to `sysdate` to avoid problems with time, if you need.